# Seguir el camino para construir breadcrumb en aplicación web (django)

Tags: php, html, django, web

En una aplicación web que estoy desarrollando con django me encuentro con la necesidad de almacenar de alguna manera el camino que sigue el usuario para llegar a una página web para construir un breadcrumb. ¿Cómo se suele resolver este tipo de situaciones? ¿Se hace uso de SESSION?

No sé si quedar claro el problema, así que lo intento aclarar con el siguiente ejemplo: en una página web **B.html** se puede llegar desde **A1.html** o desde **A2.html**. Cuando se llega desde **A1.html** se tendría el siguiente breadcrumb:

A1 / B

Y si se llega desde **A2.html** se tendría el breadcrumb:

A2 / B

Es un ejemplo simple, pero se puede complicar. Por ejemplo, llegar a D por varios caminos:
A / B / C / D
E / F / C / D

¿Cómo sé en D.html el camino seguido? ¿Qué solución se da a este tipo de situaciones?

Comment: echa un ojo a https://djangopackages.org/search/?q=breadcrumbs

Comment: Gracias Zartch, he echado un vistazo al enlace y creo que algo así puede resolver mi problema :D